# Confusion related to hidden Markov model

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model

I am referring to this tutorial: [A Tutorial on Hidden Markov Models and Selected Applications in Speech Recognition](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs4758/2012sp/materials/hmm_paper_rabiner.pdf). I am a bit confused about the forward algorithm.

From the tutorial:

> If we examine the computation involved in the calculation of
>   $\alpha_t(j)$, $1\leq t\leq T$ and $1\leq j\leq N$, it requires the order of $N^2T$
>   calculations.

I didn't exactly get why it is $N^2T$. Further they have compared it to $2TN^T$ when calculating $P(O|\lambda)$. I am also not sure how they can compare calculation complexity for $P(O|\lambda)$ against $\alpha_t(j)$. They are not even same are they?

Comment: the linked pdf is not searchable.Where exactly (pdf - page number etc.) did you find the quoted statement ?

Comment: It is right after equation no 22 in the pdf